# "had better find" or "had better found"

Tags: grammar

I recently wrote "we had better find a way to do X" but a proofreader has corrected this to "we had better found a way to do X".  Which is correct and why?

Comment: "Had better find," definitely.  The only way I can think of that "had better found" would be correct would be in something like "If he wants to be the new Carnegie he had better found a charitable organization."

Comment: The modal paraphrase _(had) better_ (always past tense, so no inflection; negative _(had) better not_; _had_ usually contracted to _-'d_, often deleted) means _should_. And, like _should,_ and all other modals, lexical or periphrastic, it must be followed by a verb in the **infinitive** form. Which one of _find_ and _found_ is the infinitive form?

Comment: Perhaps the proofreader only recognizes the contracted form of 'had better'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curiously, I believe both of these sentences are correct; however they do not share a meaning.

**We had better find a way to do X.**
This suggests that "we" should ***discover*** an existing way to do X.

**We had better found a way to do X.**
This suggests that "we" should ***invent*** a new way to do X.

This obviously relies on the usage of the verb "to found", which is not to be confused with the past tense of the verb "to find".

However, if the intent of the sentence is to use a tense of the verb "to find", then the correct construction using "found" would be:

**We had better have found a way to do X.**
This changes the meaning to indicate that "we" *may* have discovered an existing way to do X, but the speaker (who is part of the group "we") is uncertain about it. There is an implied "already" in this sentence (as "We had better have already found a way to do X.").

Answer (score 0):

Well grammatically neither of the sentences is incorrect, both are conveying a different idea in whichever way they're used. Had better find, is generally used to talk about a future event, where a "suggested idea" is thought to be indispensable to accomplishing/achieving something. Eg. a) We'd better start scoring some goals, if we're to have any chance of winning the Championship, b) We'd better find a way to stop conceding goals.

The other usage, we'd better found would be more applicable in talking about a past event that hasn't gone as planned,for eg. We'd have found a winning formula by now. The winning formula, which can be believed to have been in question for a long time in the past, hasn't yet been figured-out.

To crack open the difference, let's have a look at two similar looking situation, 1) We'd better learnt how this machine works 2) We'd better learn how this machine works. The first example with past tense of learn, is expressing an idea, well maybe about a perennial issue with the lack of knowledge of using the machine, the second sentence, with present form of learn is used to talk about a future time, where learning the use of machine would benefit in something. More importantly, the use of "if" in such sentences is a must.